# Where can I find simple free .mp3 theme for my game?

Tags: open-source, themes, mp3

Where can I find simple free .mp3 theme for my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, [14 awesome open source music sites for digital creatives.](http://blog.webdistortion.com/2009/02/21/11-awesome-open-source-music-sites-for-digital-creatives/)

Answer (score 1):

Newgrounds is a great resources for Audio

http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/

Just give some credit to the author and most of the time you're ok :D